# Missing GUI elements when adding from different files

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to add GUIs, created from individual files and add them into my main code.

While it seems to be working, kind of, however, it is missing some elements. For example, in my GridPane, there are a label and a text, both of which are missing. Likewise, for my treeview, there is a treeitem within, however, that is missing as well.

What I am trying to attempt is to reduce the amount of code in the main field and as well as to call relevant events between the Guis, eg. if I select something in the TreeView, that selected TreeItem information will be populated in the GridPane.

Client.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Client extends Application
{
    private treeviewGui tvGui;
    private gridpaneGui inputFieldsGui;
    
    
    public void init()
    {
        tvGui = new treeviewGui();
        inputFieldsGui = new gridpaneGui();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage topView)
    {
        topView.setTitle("Test Application");
        
        HBox mainLayout = new HBox(10);
        mainLayout.getChildren().addAll(tvGui, inputFieldsGui);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        topView.centerOnScreen();
        topView.setScene(scene);
        topView.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        launch(argv);
    }
}
```

treeviewGui.java

```
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class treeviewGui extends TreeView
{
    private TreeView treeview;

    public treeviewGui()
    {
        treeview = new TreeView();
        preload();

    }
    
    private void preload()
    {
        TreeItem<String> newTI = new TreeItem<>("blah");
        treeview.setRoot(newTI);
    }
    
}
```

gridPane.java

```
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class gridpaneGui extends GridPane
{
    private GridPane gridPane;
    public Text fnameTxt;
    
    public gridpaneGui()
    {
        gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);

        // First Name
        Label fnameLbl = new Label("First Name");
        fnameTxt = new Text("-");
        
        gridPane.addRow(0, fnameLbl, fnameTxt);
    }
    
    public void setFname(String nameStr)
    {
        fnameTxt.setText(nameStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the `TreeViewGUI` instance is not the same instance as the `treeView` field inside that class. Same problem with `GridPaneGUI` and `gridPane`. What you're doing there doesn't make much sense anyway. If you're going to extend a UI class then you should be adding the labels and such to `this`. But you should also consider if you really need to be extending UI classes.

Comment: Hi @Slaw, thank you for your replies. Would you mind giving me an example to elaborate on what you mention if possible?

Comment: Your `GridPaneUI` class extends `GridPane`. That means it **is-a** `GridPane`. Get rid of the `gridPane` field and simply add the elements to the `GridPaneUI` instance.

Comment: Get rid of `private GridPane gridPane;` and `gridPane = new GridPane();`. Replace all the other `gridPane` with `this`.